# Pause ‘for’ after every 5 loops

Tags: bash

I’ve got this bash script to download 52k files:

```
for i in {1..52000};
do wget -c "download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=$i" ; 
done
```

However the server gives me an 429 error.

How can I pause the loop for X amount of time after every 5 files that are downloaded?

Comment: `(( i % 5 == 0 )) && sleep 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `i` is a multiple of five, sleep.

```
for i in {1..52000}; do
    wget -c "download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=$i"
    ((i % 5)) || sleep $X
done
```

Note that `((expr))` returns the Boolean value of `expr`, where false=0 and true=1, which is the opposite of normal Bash return codes. That's why you have to use OR `||` instead of AND `&&`. If that's too confusing, use this instead: `((i % 5 == 0)) && ...`

Comment: There is the `-w` or `--wait=$seconds` and also `--limit-rate=$amount` in my wget according to the man pages `wget(1)`. Maybe not what you're asking for but you can check it out.